# Why is JavaFX API not included in Java 8 J2SE?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

Does anyone have any idea why JavaFX 8 still isn't an everyday J2SE API in the upcoming Java 8?

The technology diagram showing all the Java components clearly excludes JavaFX from the J2SE stack.

I'd like to see JavaFX and Swing APIs side-by-side in the JDK javadocs.. and wonder why Oracle doesn't/can't give us that?

BTW, on the topic of JavaFX's different status (compared to other standards included in the J2SE), can anyone explain why the authors of JavaFX felt it absolutely necessary to re-invent the wheel creating AWT/Swing-incompatible concepts like FX Fonts, FX Colors, and the like?

Answer (score 3):

**[JavaFX Roadmap.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/roadmap-1446331.html)**

According to the [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html)-

> As of JavaFX 2.2 and Java SE 7 update 6, the JavaFX libraries are
> installed as part of Java SE;

For the swing part-

> Is JavaFX replacing Swing as the new client UI library for Java SE?
>
> Yes. However, Swing will remain part of the Java SE specification for
> the foreseeable future, and therefore included in the JRE.

JavaFX is broad enough to have a separate hierarchy just like Java SE or Java EE.

You can see the definition [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/firstcup/doc/gkhoy.html).

**Java SE**

> When most people think of the Java programming language, they think of
> the Java SE API. Java SE's API provides the core functionality of the
> Java programming language. It defines everything from the basic types
> and objects of the Java programming language to high-level classes
> that are used for networking, security, database access, graphical
> user interface (GUI) development, and XML parsing.

**Java EE**

> The Java EE platform is built on top of the Java SE platform. The Java
> EE platform provides an API and runtime environment for developing and
> running large-scale, multi-tiered, scalable, reliable, and secure
> network applications.

**Java ME**

> The Java ME platform provides an API and a small-footprint virtual
> machine for running Java programming language applications on small
> devices, like mobile phones. The API is a subset of the Java SE API,
> along with special class libraries useful for small device application
> development. Java ME applications are often clients of Java EE
> platform services.

**JavaFX**

> JavaFX is a platform for creating rich internet applications using a
> lightweight user-interface API. JavaFX applications use
> hardware-accelerated graphics and media engines to take advantage of
> higher-performance clients and a modern look-and-feel as well as
> high-level APIs for connecting to networked data sources. JavaFX
> applications may be clients of Java EE platform services.

Comment: "Installed as part of" is not the same as living side-by-side in the javadocs. If you look at http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/index.html
 then you can clearly see (right of diagram) that the J2SE boundary ends just before JavaFX. Hence JavaFX is not part of J2SE. Why? What's the obstacle? What magic prevents JavaFX APIs from being just like Swing's (for example) ?

Comment: @Vincent I edited and put a link to http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/firstcup/doc/gkhoy.html

Answer (score 3):

JavaFX is planned to become a standart part of JavaSE in the time frame of JavaSE 9 (as a JSR).

In the mean time, Oracle ships JavaFX as part of its JavaSE implementation (but other vendors most likely won't).

> why the authors of JavaFX felt it absolutely necessary to re-invent
>   the wheel creating AWT/Swing-incompatible concepts like FX Fonts, FX
>   Colors, and the like?

JavaFX is a modern UI toolkit using a software stack which works closely with the graphic card, if available.

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX is part of JavaSE in JDK7 and on the default classpath from Java 8: you won't need to do anything special to use JavaFX components (apart from adding relevant `import` statements, just like with swing).

Regarding your last question, I can't speak for the designers of the API, but since fonts and colours can be imported via a css file, the resulting APIs are somewhat close to whatever you can specify in a css file, e.g. a font belongs to a family, has a style and a size.