# Why is JavaFX Documentation seperate from Java 8 Documentation?

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2, java-8

I recently learned that Java FX2 is replacing Swing for GUI development in Java. I was trying to check it out in the API documentation and could not find `javafx` listed like `javax.swing` is. I found that the documentation for JavaFX was created but **seperate** from Java 8 docs.

My question is, why would Oracle do this? Is there something about the structure of the API that I do not understand?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18441401/2711488

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaFX is not jsred and an implementation detail of oraclejdk/openjdk, whereas swing is part of the standard

Comment: Okay would you mind explaining the difference? Does this mean thst by downloading Java 8 sdk im not automatically set up to write and compile FX programs?

Comment: Not any SDK - for oraclejdk and openjdk you are setup but eg ibm java does not come with javafx. This is also the reason javafx is on the extension classpath.

Comment: Okay. But if its meant to "replace" swing as oracle says why would it not be a standard for all jdk?

Comment: @bmcentee148 JavaFX is not part of the Java standards because it has not yet gone through the standards process.  There is a [layman's view of the Java standardization process for Java 9 here](http://www.takipiblog.com/java-9-the-ultimate-feature-list/).  It is possible that JavaFX will be standardized for Java 9, but it is currently not on the list of standardization efforts accepted for Java 9.  If you like, you could ask more about the standardization process for JavaFX on the [openjfx-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev).

Comment: @bmcentee148: Giving it’s quality (and design flaws in the first place) I doubt that JavaFX will ever replace Swing. The idea of building a scene graph with limited extensibility has failed with Java 3D as well as with the Java Media Framework and I don’t know why the never learn from that…

Comment: @tomsontom: openjdk has no javafx as well

Comment: @SergeyGrive sure it does and IIRC fx is an openjdk project which even has jeps in java9 - see https://jdk8.java.net/download.html which is openjdk - linux distro although ship openjdk without it

Comment: @tomsontom: of course, that’s why I *know* that it’s unusable as even the simplest tasks are impossible due to design mistakes or bugs which you can’t workaround due to the limitations of the design. Just a simple example: try to tell the Html Editor to not lose the entire work when the user clicks on a link. Impossible, as altering the behavior of a clicked link has not been foreseen. Besides the performance aspects of reparsing the entire Html document when a single character has been inserted, as no other way of modifying the document has been foreseen, not even internally…